# K3b - cdrecord has no permission

Tags: permissions, k3b

I use Ubuntu 12.04. Today I tried to burn an ISO file in a DVD-R disk using K3b. It used to work, but today, after one and a half minutes, it stopped saying that "cdrecord has no permission to open the device". I searched for a solution, and I found that I had to do something with k3bsetup. I tried to use it, but I had no idea what to do, and I couldn't find a guide, so I checked *cdrecord* and clicked apply. Now there is another error; it says "cdrecord returns an unknown error! (code 254)". What should I do?

Comment: If you are an Ubuntu user, you don't need any burning software. Brasero Disc Burner is includen in Ubuntu, and my opinion: Is much better. So why not try it?

Comment: For newer versions of ubuntu take a look here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032903/problem-with-k3b-in-18-04-releases-cdrecord-has-no-permission-to-open-the-devi

Comment: If the problem comes from burning a BD disk then you cannot use Brasero, so ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had similar problem and fixed it with the following steps:

1. Open k3b.
2. Go to Settings -> Setup system Permissions.
3. Select all options and apply.

It will ask for your password (you must be admin).

If it doesn't works, open k3b from terminal with `sudo -H k3b`, and try same steps as before.

Should help.

Comment: I selected all options except the "Use burning group", because when I tried, it said "There isn't group "burning" ". After that, there are some other errors, such as "OPC failed", "probably a buffer underrun occured", and once the "cdrecord returns an unknown error! (code 254)". I also tried reset, but still nothing.

Comment: I tried today again to write a DVD and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to "select all options", and selecting the drive and closing the dialog had no effect. However, sudo k3b did work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This solve the problem:

```
cd /usr/bin/
sudo chmod 0755 cdrdao
sudo chmod a+s cdrdao
sudo chown root:root cdrdao
sudo chmod 0755 wodim
sudo chmod a+s wodim
sudo chown root:root wodim
```