# No CD/DVD/BD writer found on k3b

Tags: k3b, burner

Even if it is seen into drives my system won't recognize the writer... since 15.04 update...

With k3b started as root the problem stays the same

[image: system configuration problem]
[image: even if seeing into drives]

Dont understand why I cannot write, is there a driver change on last kernel?

```
sudo cat /proc/sys/dev/cdrom/info 
CD-ROM information, Id: cdrom.c 3.20 2003/12/17

drive name:             sr0
drive speed:            24
drive # of slots:       1
Can close tray:         1
Can open tray:          1
Can lock tray:          1
Can change speed:       1
Can select disk:        0
Can read multisession:  1
Can read MCN:           1
Reports media changed:  1
Can play audio:         1
Can write CD-R:         0
Can write CD-RW:        0
Can read DVD:           1
Can write DVD-R:        0
Can write DVD-RAM:      0
Can read MRW:           1
Can write MRW:          1
Can write RAM:          1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [K3b - cdrecord has no permission](http://askubuntu.com/questions/287308/k3b-cdrecord-has-no-permission)

Comment: @dobey thx but nope

Answer (score 0):

you need to be in the "burn" group of your operating system...

you can do this through the wizanrd in k3b below "settings -> system settings"

Comment: and your question is possibly a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/287308/k3b-cdrecord-has-no-permission?rq=1

Comment: groups command result: 

    pg adm dialout cdrom plugdev lpadmin admin sambashare git burning

Comment: The group alone is not the solution - the wizard gives the device to the group with rw rights.... check that with "ls -lah /dev/sr" or whatever your devicename is...