# Kubuntu 14.04, K3B, burning group is missing / there's no burning group

Tags: permissions, kubuntu, dvd, burning, k3b

I tried to burn a DVD with K3B (a data project) but have some problems. K3B does not detect an empty DVD.

I burned a DVD using K3B like 3 days ago, and I did it with success. I don't know what happened, maybe some updates issue?

Anyway, I tried the advice given here: [K3b - cdrecord has no permission](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287308/k3b-cdrecord-has-no-permission), but no success, K3B tells me that there's no group like burning (yes, I'm a root).

I tried to burn a DVD with Brasero, and I burned it successfully. However, that does not solve my issue, since I prefer using K3B and simply want to fix it. Any ideas?

```
$ sudo ls -lah /dev/sr0
brw-rw-rw-+ 1 root cdrom 11, 0 mar  6 12:56 /dev/sr0

$ groups
katie adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare bumblebee
```

Comment: Just to check, have you tried selecting all options _except_ "Use burning group", as mentioned in the comments in [post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/287308)?

Comment: Also you mentioned that "K3B does not detect an empty DVD". Does it produce any error?

Answer (score 6):

**Fixing the 'burning group' error:**

I can confirm this issue with Ubuntu 14.04 and k3b run as either ordinary user or running with `sudo k3b`. The solution on my system was to manually create the group from the commandline before opening k3b, demonstrated on my system as follows:

```
andrew@corinth:~$ sudo addgroup burning
[sudo] password for andrew: 
Adding group `burning' (GID 1001) ...
Done.
andrew@corinth:~$
```

After this add yourself to the new 'burning' group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G burning $USER
```

And then going to the k3b configuration screen:

```
k3b -->  Settings --> Setup System Permissions
```

and checking all of the following boxes:

1. Use burning group: burning (this should work now)
2. Devices: (Select the device you wish to use)
3. External Programs: Found Programs (select the applications you wish to use)

Press 'Apply' and all should now be well :).

**Further Error Messages?**

If however you managed to create the required group but continue to get odd burning problems and errors consider adding Brandon Snider's CDRTools PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:brandonsnider/cdrtools
sudo apt-get update
```

And then installing Jörg Schilling's cdrtools and friends (this will safely replace the Debian fork burning tools):

```
sudo apt-get install cdda2wav cdrecord mkisofs
```

And finally returning to:

```
k3b -->  Settings --> Setup System Permissions
```

to setup the new applications with the appropriate permissions.

Another few things to try if problems persist:

1. Try a different brand of disk and if using DVD -R try DVD +R and the reverse.
2. Experiment with turning Nautilus ['auto-mount' off and on](https://askubuntu.com/q/89244/57576). The [k3b FAQs](http://www.k3b.org/faq) implicate auto-mount in a variety of errors when burning.

Finally here is a screenshot showing the final settings on my own system:

[image]

Comment: Sooo, now I messed up... Did everything you wrote, but after pressing the Apply button, I couldn't burn it. So I did further steps. Now the result is I have nothing in `Found Programs` section in `k3b --> Settings --> Setup System Permissions` and I'm getting the message: `Can't find cdrdao, cdrecord, growisofs binaries.` However, I have them installed :( – Katie

Comment: Oops! Use the following command to add yourself to the 'burning' group: `sudo usermod -a -G burning $USER`. I will add this to my answer + screenshot...

Comment: It didn't help. Now I don't see the message `Can't find cdrdao, cdrecord, growisofs binaries` and have something like this in my settings: http://s17.postimg.org/u0qehyuhr/screen11.png but `k3b` still does not see an empty DVD and says: `Please insert an empty DVD drive` while it's already inside ...

Comment: So looks like k3b is now set up perfectly but still no luck :(. Have you experimented with a different dvd type? Although that particular drive will use +R and -R try a different brand and type... Also have a look in Settings -->Configure k3b ... Devices and make sure you have a Write Device enabled. But I confess I am running out of ideas soon :((

Comment: Remaining idea comes from the k3b FAqs where auto-mounting can cause a variety of issues: http://www.k3b.org/faq. This can be done readily  (and reversed as easily) and it would be great if you could do this as a test: http://askubuntu.com/q/89244/57576 . If this makes a difference I will write it up as part of my answer...

Comment: The easier command to add your own user to a group is `sudo adduser $USER groupname`.