# Just installed K3B, and I cannot get it to work at all

Tags: sound, permissions, mount, cd, k3b

I recently upgraded from an obsolete machine and a no-longer-supported version of Ubuntu to a newer, faster machine with Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver, 64-bit). I am running MATE as my user interface (version 1.20.1).

On my old machine, burning audio CDs with K3B was virtually effortless. Whenever I hit "burn", the process usually went smoothly and successfully.

On my new machine with the new OS, I get the following error message:

*"cdrecord has no permission to open the device
Modify the device settings in K3B to solve this problem. "*

Here is the debugging information:

---

### Devices

hp DVD A  DH16ABLH 3HD9 (/dev/sr0, CD-R, CD-RW, CD-ROM, DVD-ROM, DVD-R, DVD-RW, DVD-R DL, DVD+R, DVD+RW, DVD+R DL) [DVD-ROM, DVD-R Sequential, DVD-R Dual Layer Sequential, DVD-R Dual Layer Jump, DVD-RAM, DVD-RW Restricted Overwrite, DVD-RW Sequential, DVD+RW, DVD+R, DVD+R Dual Layer, CD-ROM, CD-R, CD-RW] [SAO, TAO, RAW, SAO/R96P, SAO/R96R, RAW/R16, RAW/R96P, RAW/R96R, Restricted Overwrite, Layer Jump] [%7]

### System

K3b Version: 17.12.3
KDE Version: 5.44.0
Qt Version:  5.9.5
Kernel:      5.3.0-46-generic

### Used versions

cdrecord: 1.1.11

### cdrecord

/usr/bin/wodim: Operation not permitted. Warning: Cannot raise RLIMIT_MEMLOCK limits.
/usr/bin/wodim: Resource temporarily unavailable. Cannot get mmap for 12587008 Bytes on /dev/zero.
Text len: 54
TOC Type: 0 = CD-DA

### cdrecord command:

/usr/bin/wodim -v gracetime=2 dev=/dev/sr0 speed=40 -sao driveropts=burnfree textfile=/tmp/k3b.oo7726 -useinfo -audio /tmp/k3b_audio_0_01.inf /tmp/k3b_audio_0_02.inf /tmp/k3b_audio_0_03.inf /tmp/k3b_audio_0_04.inf /tmp/k3b_audio_0_05.inf /tmp/k3b_audio_0_06.inf /tmp/k3b_audio_0_07.inf /tmp/k3b_audio_0_08.inf /tmp/k3b_audio_0_09.inf /tmp/k3b_audio_0_10.inf /tmp/k3b_audio_0_11.inf

---

I checked the permission settings in K3B, and everything looks the way it supposedly should. Still, I get the error message every time I try to burn a CD.

Furthermore, K3B (version 17.12.3) saves K3B project files in the form of ZIP files instead of the K3B files that the old version used. Consequently, when I try to open a K3B project file, it doesn't show up in the program's "open" command.

What we have here is either a very buggy program or something which can hopefully be easily and quickly solved.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032903/problem-with-k3b-in-18-04-releases-cdrecord-has-no-permission-to-open-the-devi?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did see that page, but the error message shown on that page was worded slightly differently from the one that I got, leading me to think that the solution described on that page might not work for this particular version of K3b. Also, I'm nervous about running K3b as root, as that posting seems to be indicating.

Comment: My question for this question, why don't you consider other CD/DVD burners? I haven't had no problem with Brasero or XFburn for many years. `sudo apt install xfburn`