# K3b help needed - cdrecord has no permission to open the device

Tags: ubuntu-mate, k3b

I am having problems using K3b.

I am trying to erase a CD-RW disk.

I am getting this error box.

[image: b b]

Comment: Is this any help: https://askubuntu.com/q/1032903/57576 ?

Comment: @andrew.46 I followed the recommendation, but I got this message. mkisofs crashed. Probably a buffer overrun occured. Please use a lower burning speed.